# silverlight 3.0 control in master page in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Can any body tell me how to add silverlight 3.0 control in master page in asp.net 3.5 (ide VS2008)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i done by simply copy script and object tag from your test page for xmal and put in master page that's it in content place holder of master page it wont get displayed for me

Answer (score 1):

Have a contentplaceholder in the master. Then create a webform for the masterpage. Place the silverlight control in the content part with the contentplaceholder set to masterpage contentplaceholder.

Comment: nice. If the answer above was helpful then can you accept it by clicking the tick mark. Or if you have solved it by any other way then can you update it on the comment. It will certainly prove helpful for somebody else searching for something similar.

Comment: i done by simply copy script and object tag from your test page for xmal and put in master page that's it in content place holder of master page it wont get displayed for me

Comment: If you can edit you question and add the piece of code for it then will be glad to help you out.